# Mysql in a multithreaded program - my_thread_global_end()

Tags: mysql, c

I'm having serious problems with mysql using pthreads. The error I get after ending my program:

"Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit"

I called mysql_library_init in main before starting any threads. For the sake of it, I just started 1 thread. After the thread is closed (using pthread_join), I call mysql_library_end in main. In the pthread itself I call mysql_init. For some reason this seems incorrect cause I get the error. I use MySQL 5.6 and link with libmysqlclient.a.

The mysql manual is extremely unclear and contradictory, so I hope someone with a logical mind can explain this to me:

"In a nonmulti-threaded environment, mysql_init invokes mysql_library_init automatically as necessary. However, mysql_library_init is not thread-safe in a multi-threaded environment, and thus neither is mysql_init. Before calling mysql_init, either call mysql_library_init prior to spawning any threads, or use a mutex to protect the mysql_library_init call. This should be done prior to any other client library call."

First line: So mysql_init ONLY invokes mysql_library_init in a NONmulti-threaded environment "when needed" (when is it needed anyway in a NONmulti-threaded environment?) and so I can conlcude from this that mysql_init() thinks it is NOT needed in a multi-threaded environment? I guess not, so fine, I call mysql_library_init in my main... Then I read everywhere I should also call mysql_init within the thread after that. I want each thread to have his own connection, so fine, I also do that so each thread have their own MYSQL struct. But the manual sais mysql_init is not thread safe... Uhm, ok... So just with 1 thread, I still have the problem...

```
main -> mysql_library_init
main -> create 1 pthread
pthread -> mysql_init
pthread -> mysql_real_connect
pthread -> mysql_close
....
```

I press Ctrl C after a few seconds (mysql was closed by now in the thread) so the cleaning up starts:

```
main -> pthread_cancel
main -> pthread_join
main -> mysql_library_end
```

RESULT: Error in my_thread_global_end: 1 threads didn't exit

........

Comment: I forgot to mention: the thread is still alive when I press Ctrl C, it was blocking on a semaphore (for other purposes) and will stop blocking as soon as I hit Ctrl C...

Comment: No I don't, does that command exist? Can't find it in the online manual. If you rather want me to paste some code, I will.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main( void )
{
   if ( mysql_library_init( 0, NULL, NULL ) != 0 ) { ... }
   if ( mysql_thread_safe() ) { ... } // This goes fine

   sem_init( &queue.totalStored, 0, 0 );
   pthread_mutex_init( &mutex_bees, NULL );
   pthread_create( &workerbees[tid], &attr, BeeWork, ( void * ) tid );
   pthread_attr_destroy( &attr );

   while ( recv_signal == 0 )
   {
      errno = 0;
      sock_c = accept( sock_s, NULL, NULL );

      if ( ( sock_c == -1 ) && ( errno == EINTR ) )
      {
         // do stuff
         if ( recv_signal == SIGHUP ) { /* do stuff*/ }
      } else { /* do stuff */ }
   }

   // CLEANUP
   close( sock_s );
   RC = pthread_cancel( workerbees[tid] );
   if ( RC != 0 ) { Log( L_ERR, "Unsuccessful pthread_cancel()" ); }

   // WAIT FOR THREADS TO FINISH WORK AND EXIT
   RC = pthread_join( workerbees[tid], &res );
   if ( RC != 0 ) { Log( L_ERR, "Error: Unsuccessful pthread_join()" ); }

   if ( res == PTHREAD_CANCELED )
   { /* print debug stuff */ }
   else { /* print debug stuff */ }

   mysql_library_end();
   sem_destroy( &queue.totalStored );
   exit( 0 );
}

void *BeeWork( void *t )
{
   // DISABLE SIGNALS THAT main() ALREADY LISTENS TO
   sigemptyset( &sigset );
   sigaddset( &sigset, SIGINT );
   sigaddset( &sigset, SIGTERM );
   sigaddset( &sigset, SIGQUIT );
   sigaddset( &sigset, SIGHUP );
   pthread_sigmask( SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL );

   MYSQL *conn;
   conn = mysql_init( NULL );
   if ( ! mysql_real_connect( conn, server, prefs.mysql_user, prefs.mysql_pass, prefs.mysql_db, 0, prefs.mysql_sock, 0 ) ) { /* error */ }
   mysql_close( conn );

   // Do stuff
   ...
   pthread_exit( ( void * ) t );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can answer my own question, I found out my pthread cleanup handler was not executed (installed with pthread_cleanup_push) and the end of the code with pthread_exit was called sooner than main could cancel the thread. I did a pthread_cleanup_pop( 0 ) and changed it to pthread_cleanup_pop( 1 ) so the cleanup handler also got executed when the thread exits sooner than main could cancel. In this cleanup handler, now mysql_thread_end actually got a chance to run and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Addition: **Apparently, the MySQL client library is not designed to use connection handles (`MYSQL*`) across threads.**

Do not pass a `MYSQL*` from one thread to another.

Do not use `std::async` or simlilar in conjunction with MySQL functions. (Code may or may not be executed in a separate thread.)